# Active Admin - Custom filter panel

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activeadmin

I'm trying to build a completely custom filter panel. More specifically I'd like to customize the layout (panel and not sidebar) and have the result updated 'live' via AJAX (no need to click on Submit button). 
Which is the right way to do that with Active Admin? Do I actually have to use 'register_page'?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can fully customize how your index renders with a partial.

in admin/my_model.rb :

```
index do
    render "my_partial"
end
```

in views/admin/my_model/_my_partial.html.erb :

```
<h1>My Partial</1>

<%= semantic_form_for :my_model, url: my_form_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs do %>
        <%= f.input :my_field %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.actions do %>
        <%= f.action :submit %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and of course from there you can add any JS you'd like in order to achieve your AJAX features

Comment: I actually need to have both a "search form" and the table with the results in the same page.
Tried something like
`index do
panel do
   render :partial => "my_search_form"
end
column :a
column :b
end`
and then I have `_my_search_form.html.erb` which is something like
`<%= form_tag %>
<%= label_tag "1" %>
<%= label_tag "2" %>
<% end %>`
but the result is that everything inside <form> is rendered outside, i.e. the following HTML is produced
'<form ...>
</form>
<label> 1 </label>
<label> 2 </label>'